# How to test random values using Selenium+Appium and java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am trying to perform automation on a StaticText field on iOS device using Appium. I can able to get the text and print it.

```
Object value = js.executeScript("UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().collectionViews()[0].cells()[0].staticTexts()[\"abc\"].value();"); 

System.out.println(value);
```

Sample Output: From 20/min

What I am trying now is as it is a random value, Everytime I run the test I will get different output. As I want to assert the output I am unable to give a static value and assert it.

Is there any way I can pass the test even if I get different values everytime I run the test.

Answer (score 0):

**API usage**.

The only way to do this is get the random value as generated for the `StaticText` field using the API which has been called by the application code as well.

Since that is how you can end up having the ***same + valid*** value to be asserted during your test.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a different output value and verifying that value is not your goal why do you want to assert it? Just remove assert and your test will pass irrespective of output value!